# How to select object at index in WP7?

Tags: windows, arrays, windows-phone-7, indexing

I have an array that has specified colors like this,

```
Object[] l_colarray = new Object[13] { Colors.Black,Colors.Blue,Colors.Brown,Colors.Cyan,Colors.DarkGray,
                Colors.Gray,Colors.Green,Colors.LightGray,Colors.Magenta,Colors.Orange,Colors.Purple,Colors.Red,Colors.White};
```

How do i select an index,(objectatindex:i, was used in iOS). Kindly help me with this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what you mean by "select an index". Do you mean simply:

```
object color = l_colarray[index];
```

? Note that if all the values are `Color` values you'd be better off with:

```
Color[] colors = { Colors.Black, Colors.Blue, Colors.Brown, Colors.Cyan,
    Colors.DarkGray, Colors.Gray, Colors.Green, Colors.LightGray,
    Colors.Magenta, Colors.Orange,Colors.Purple,Colors.Red,Colors.White };

...

Color color = colors[index];
```

Notes:

- When you're initializing an array variable in the same statement as its declaration, you don't need the "new TypeName[]" part
- You don't need to specify the size when you use "new TypeName[] { ... }"

Comment: Thanks for the ans, this one seems to be working.. Thanks again!

Comment: @indiaxxo: If you're really new to C#, I would *strongly* advise you to put down Windows Phone 7 to start with, and get an *introductory* book to C#. WP7 has enough quirks of its own without you tripping up over basics - it really helps if you've got a solid understanding of the *language* before you start to encounter those mobile-specific quirks.

Comment: Yeah I shifted myself onto WP7 from iOS. Thanks for the advise, that'd be of great help to me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about selecting in a ui...

There's an excellent q&a set of info for listbox and selecteditem (and selectedindex) at http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/WP7-ListBox-SelectedItem

The answer you need depends on how you are entering sata into the list box - e.g. Are you using databinding.

At a simple level, if you're using codebehind to manipulate the list box then you can use:

```
 ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 6;
```

---

If you are talking about objective-c language level selecting... Then you can just use array accessors in c#:

```
 var item = l_colarray[6];
```

---

One good place To start on iOS to wp7 porting is http://wp7mapping.interoperabilitybridges.com/library

Comment: Thanks for the ans... I'm trying!